# Null Pointer Exception when adding view to scroll view

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Okay, so i created a custom view with a couple layouts and textviews. I made an object that creates the view dynamically. Heres the code that makes the view and sets the TextViews....

```
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.run_info_layout, null);

    TextView infoP, in;
    infoP = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvInfoParameter);
    in = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);

    infoP.setText(ip);
    in.setText(i);
```

In an activity i have i have it creating some of these objects using this code....

```
    runInfo.add(new RunInfoLayout("Final Time", run.getTime(), RunEnding.this));
    runInfo.add(new RunInfoLayout("Distance", Float.toString(run.getDistance()), RunEnding.this));
    runInfo.add(new RunInfoLayout("Started", run.getBTime(), RunEnding.this));
    runInfo.add(new RunInfoLayout("Ended", run.getETime(), RunEnding.this));
    runInfo.add(new RunInfoLayout("Number of laps", Integer.toString(numberOfLaps), RunEnding.this));
```

I have a loop that goes through runInfo which is an ArrayList and adds the views to a ScrollView.....

```
    for(int x = 0; x < runInfo.size(); x++){
        llRunInfo.addView(runInfo.get(x).getView());
    }
```

llRunInfo is the LinearLayout in the ScrollView. That getView() method just returns the view it made in the earlier code. The problem is at the addView() line. I'm getting a nullPointerException there. Here's the logcat....

```
07-25 12:42:25.223: E/AndroidRuntime(31056): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 12:42:25.223: E/AndroidRuntime(31056):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3148)
07-25 12:42:25.223: E/AndroidRuntime(31056):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3131)
07-25 12:42:25.223: E/AndroidRuntime(31056):    at com.TBJsoft.runprogress.RunEnding.build(RunEnding.java:55)
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `llRunInfo`?

Comment: What is a `RunInfoLayout`, and what does its `getView()` method do? It looks like it's returning `null`.

Comment: I initialize it before the code where i add the objects to runInfo. Its a class i made, it returns the view that gets created with this code

Comment: inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.run_info_layout, null);

    TextView infoP, in;
    infoP = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvInfoParameter);
    in = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);

    infoP.setText(ip);
    in.setText(i);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you're seeing the NullPointer, keep in mind `ScrollView` can only have one child.

Out of curiosity, why are you doing all of this by hand? Why not just have an `ArrayAdapter` in a `ListView`? You can still use your custom view as the `ArrayAdapter`'s custom view, but this way you're letting `ListView` take care of your view recycling - which I assume you're not handling doing your own `addView` in a `ScrollView`, you'll probably have some memory and scrolling issues when your data set grows.

Comment: Well I'm still kind of new to this, so i don't know about all of the android stuff.

Comment: This may be a good introduction for ListView and what you're trying to achieve. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/